# Selectors within radio buttons not allowing selection in first selector

Tags: jquery, html

I have two radio buttons.  Under each radio button is a selector, with both of having default set to `disabled`.  When I click on one of the radio buttons, the corresponding selector under it becomes enabled -- `.prop('disabled', false)`.  When I click on the first radio button and make a selection, when my form is submitted, the option I'd selected is NOT selected -- it stays at the initial value of `select_option` when it goes to the database.  But when I click on the second radio button and make a selection, the option I'd selected IS properly selected.  Here is the html (a Handlebars template)...

```
<fieldset id="class-schedule-options">
  {{> application_form/_choose_options_explained}}
  <br>
  <br>
  <div class="radio-div-applic">
    <label><input type="radio" id="sched-opt-one" name="class-schedule-options" class="radio-in-appl">{{schedule_option_one}}</label>
    <select id="five-weeks" name="class_time" class="grayout seminar-session-select" disabled>
      <option id="option-with-id" value="select_option" disabled selected> -- select an option -- </option>
      <option value="Tuesdays, 31 May - 28 June, 5:00-6:30pm">Tuesdays, 31 May - 28 June, 5:00-6:30pm</option>
      <option value="Tuesdays, 31 May - 28 June, 7:00-8:30pm">Tuesdays, 31 May - 28 June, 7:00-8:30pm</option>
      <option value="Saturdays, 4 June - 2 July, 10:30am-12:00pm">Saturdays, 4 June - 2 July, 10:30am-12:00pm</option>
      <option value="Saturdays, 4 June - 2 July, 12:30am-2:00pm">Saturdays, 4 June - 2 July, 12:30am-2:00pm</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="radio-div-applic">
    <label><input type="radio" id="sched-opt-two" name="class-schedule-options" class="radio-in-appl">{{schedule_option_two}}</label>
    <select id="one-whole-week" name="class_time" class="grayout seminar-session-select" disabled>
      <option id="option-with-id" value="select_option" disabled selected> -- select an option -- </option>
      <option value="6-10 June, 5:00-6:30pm">6-10 June, 5:00-6:30pm</option>
      <option value="6-10 June, 7:00-8:30pm">6-10 June, 7:00-8:30pm</option>
      <option value="13-17 June, 5:00-6:30pm">13-17 June, 5:00-6:30pm</option>
      <option value="13-17 June, 7:00-8:30pm">13-17 June, 7:00-8:30pm</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</fieldset> <!-- class-schedule-options -->
```

If I delete the second radio button/selector, the first radio button/selector WILL work.  Somehow the presence of the second radio button/selector causes the first one to only select the original value (`select_option`).

Here is the JS associated with this html.

```
$("#sched-opt-one, #sched-opt-two").on("click", function() {
  if (button1.checked){ // if #five-weeks selected
    $('#five-weeks').prop('disabled', false);
    $('#five-weeks').removeClass("grayout").addClass("blackin");
    $('#one-whole-week').val('select_option');
    $('#one-whole-week').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
    $('#one-whole-week').removeClass("blackin").addClass("grayout");
  }
  else if (button2.checked) { // if #one-whole-week selected
    $('#one-whole-week').prop('disabled', false);
    $('#one-whole-week').removeClass("grayout").addClass("blackin");
    $('#five-weeks').val('select_option');
    $('#five-weeks').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
    $('#five-weeks').removeClass("blackin").addClass("grayout");
  }
});
```

I can't figure out why the first (the top) radio button/selector will not allow the selection of a new `option`, when the second radio button/selector is present.

Comment: Both the selects have same `name` property. Form post refers `name=".."`. This might be an issue.

Comment: id and name should be unique, otherwise the form will send the last element that match the name... Question, the user can select both check and set both schedules? if avoiding it is what you try by giving the same name and id, it's not the right approach.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I made the two names different for the two selectors and it worked great!

Comment: Actually with the JS, I disable one selector and gray it out and set it back to the value of `select_option` if the user clicks on the other selector's radio button.  So the user will never be able to select from both selectors.